# Are there certain Google Slides AppScript that are documented but not supported?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-slides-api, google-slides

I am trying to manipulate a table in Google Slides, but there seem to be documented operations that throw errors in AppScript.

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/slides/table

The commented out lines throw the following errors:

> Updating the size of this page element type is not supported.

```
var table = (slides[page])
.insertTable(rows, columns)
.setTop (0)
.setLeft(0)
//.setWidth(presentation.getPageWidth());
//.setHeight(presentation.getPageHeight());
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this answer? I have also confirmed the same situation with you. I think that this might be a bug. Because when Slides API is used, the table which adjusted the width and height can be created. So in the current workaround, when the size of the table is required to be adjusted when the table is created, I create the table using Slides API. The sample script is as follows.

In order to use the sample script, before you run the script, please enable Slides API at Advanced Google Services and API console as follows.

#### Enable Slides API v1 at Advanced Google Services

- On script editor

  - Resources -> Advanced Google Services
  - Turn on Google Slides API v1

#### Enable Slides API at API console

- On script editor

  - Resources -> Cloud Platform project
  - View API console
  - At Getting started, click "Explore and enable APIs".
  - At left side, click Library.
  - At "Search for APIs & services", input "Slides". And click "Google Slides API".
  - Click Enable button.
  - If API has already been enabled, please don't turn off.

#### Sample script 1:

When your script is modified using Slides API, it becomes as follows.

```
var presentation = SlidesApp.getActivePresentation();
var slides = presentation.getSlides();
var resource = {"requests":[{"createTable": {
  "rows": 2,
  "columns": 3,
  "elementProperties": {
    "size": {
      "width": {"unit": "PT", "magnitude": presentation.getPageWidth()},
      "height": {"unit": "PT", "magnitude": presentation.getPageHeight()},
    },
    "pageObjectId": slides[0].getObjectId()},
  }
}]};
Slides.Presentations.batchUpdate(resource, presentation.getId());
```

#### Sample script 2:

If you want to modify the size of the existing table, you can use the following script.

```
var presentation = SlidesApp.getActivePresentation();
var slides = presentation.getSlides();
var table = slides[0].getTables()[0];
var tableObjectId = table.getObjectId();
var resource = {"requests": [
  {"updateTableColumnProperties": {
    "objectId": tableObjectId,
    "tableColumnProperties": {"columnWidth": {"unit": "PT", "magnitude": presentation.getPageWidth() / table.getNumColumns()}}, "fields": "*"}
  },
  {"updateTableRowProperties": {
    "objectId": tableObjectId,
    "tableRowProperties": {"minRowHeight":{"unit": "PT", "magnitude": presentation.getPageHeight() / table.getNumRows()}},"fields":"*"}
  }
]};
Slides.Presentations.batchUpdate(resource, presentation.getId());
```

#### References :

- [Advanced Google Services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced)
- [Google Slides API](https://developers.google.com/slides/reference/rest/)
- [CreateTableRequest](https://developers.google.com/slides/reference/rest/v1/presentations/request#createtablerequest)
- [UpdateTableColumnPropertiesRequest](https://developers.google.com/slides/reference/rest/v1/presentations/request#updatetablecolumnpropertiesrequest)
- [UpdateTableRowPropertiesRequest](https://developers.google.com/slides/reference/rest/v1/presentations/request#updatetablerowpropertiesrequest)

If this was not the workaround you want, I apologize.

Comment: Thanks! I figured that this was the case, but was looking to avoid having to change the entire scope of my project to include the API integrations. This code will be a huge help to accelerating the integration. Kind of a serious pain that it can't be manged as an method within the Table class.

Comment: @Stewart Whitman Thank you for replying. I apologize that I couldn't notice that you cannot use Slides API. Also I apologize that my answer was not useful for your situation and your issue was not resolved.

Comment: @Tanaike seems interesting ans, 
if i will use this slide API to build an add-ons then it will work without any dependencies ? like you are enabling some setting in Editor and console ?

Comment: @Puzzled Boy Thank you for replying. I would like to support you. But I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand about your current issue and your goal. So in order to correctly understand about your issue, can you post it as new question by including more information? By this, it will help users think of the solution. If you can cooperate to resolve your issue, I'm glad.